# HTML 5 Canvas: how to check all line points coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to build a simple game with a canavas: there is a shape and the user have to draw following its border, without going out of it. I have the shape, the user can draw but now I can't find a way to check when the user draw goes out of the shape border. I should check the coordinates of every point of the lines that he draws. Is it possible and how or are there any other ways? Thanks!

```
function findxy(res, e) {
            if (res == 'down') {
                if(status == 'wait'){
                    status = 'run'; 
                    startX = e.clientX -canvas2.offsetLeft;
                    startY = e.clientY -canvas2.offsetLeft;
                }
                if (status == 'run'){
                    write = true;
                    currX = e.clientX -canvas2.offsetLeft;
                    currY = e.clientY -canvas2.offsetTop;

                    context2.fillStyle = 'red';
                    context2.fillRect(currX, currY, lineWidth, lineWidth);
                }
            }
            if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
                if(status=='run'){
                    status = 'stop';
                    write = false;
                    if(won)
                        alert('You won!');
                    else
                        alert('You lose!');
                }
            }
            if (res == 'move') {
                if (write) {
                    currX = e.clientX - canvas2.offsetLeft;
                    currY = e.clientY - canvas2.offsetTop;

                    var baseData = context1.getImageData(currX, currY, 1, 1).data;
                    context2.fillStyle = 'red';
                    context2.fillRect(currX, currY, lineWidth, lineWidth);
                    if(baseData[3]!=255){
                        alert('You lose!');
                        status='lose';
                        write=false;
                    }
                    if(currX==startX && currY==startY){
                        won=true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need two canvases for this. When the user draws, you get the coordinates of where he's drawing and then check on the other canvas if it's in the shape (using getImageData to get the pixel information: if it's transparent it's not in the shape). I hope this makes sense

Comment: An alternative to @JonasGrumann's good idea is to draw the outline of your shape with path commands and then use `context.isPointInPath` to hit-test whether the mouse is moving inside or outside your defined path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I have two canvases, one for the user to draw on and one for the black box (that would your shape). When the user moves the mouse I draw a dot on the user canvas and I check on the other canvas if the mouse is on the black box.

The code:

```js
var CheckCanvases = function() {
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  this.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 80);

    canvas2.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
      var mousePosX = e.clientX;
      var mousePosY = e.clientY;

      self.checkIfMouseIsInBox(mousePosX, mousePosY);
    })
  }

  this.checkIfMouseIsInBox = function(x, y) {
    var imageData = ctx1.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    ctx2.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    //image data is an Red, Green, Blue, Alpha array -> [0, 0, 0, 0]
    //if it is [0, 0, 0, 255] it means it is not transparent, thus the mouse is in the black box
    if (imageData[3] == 255) {
      output.innerHTML = "In Box";
    } else {
      output.innerHTML = "Not in Box"
    }
  }

  this.init();
}

var checkCanvases = new CheckCanvases();
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<h3 id="output">Not in Box</h3>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now with two canvas I can check the correct drawing, although sometimes it does not seem very accurate. Now I have a small problem I don't remember to have when I started: when I draw I have a small offset beetween pointer and drawn line. I am considering canvas offset and I haven't canvas dimension in css, so from what it could be caused?

Comment: That's really hard to say without seeing a demo, could you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: I added my event function in the question, I think if there's a problem it's there.

Comment: Still, I think a fiddle would be useful. I'm thinking it might be css positioning making the clientX have problems

Comment: The problem in the linked code is that the browser's body has 10px margin as default and e.clientX doesn't take it into account. To fix it, you need to use a crossbrowser version of offsetX and offsetY instead: see http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/b4f4oqxj/3/ 
Paste that function inside findxy(res, e) and use offsetX and offsetY instead of e.clientX and e.clientY inside that function.
Buon lavoro ;)